# Cucumber with Gradle for Java

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber-jvm

I use Gradle for building my project and I have some trouble between cucumber and gradle. For example:

I have a feature file, which I run with JUnit RunWith annotation. But if I want to run 1 scenario by tag, I write this:
`-Dcucumber.options= --tags @1 @2` and try to run it.

But Gradle doesn't see this command and runs all tests. So, how can I correctly apply cucumber plugin into Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found one way to do it. All we need is to use testCompile with JUnit, not cucumber-junit and all is right.